# How to have a character move and interact with a map (in a game)?

Tags: batch-file

Something similar to rougelikes. I'm pretty good at batch but I don't know a lot of the commands needed to do something like this. I'm clueless. I've seen other people do it but I do not understand the code and the map is annoyingly redrawn every movement. If it's not/barely possible then what other language could I use?

Comment: `cmd` has no function to write to a specified location; it's line-based (because it's not a programming language but just a list of commands). That's why the "annoying redraws": you have to write the complete screen for every change somewhere (well, it is possible (see "snake.bat" from dbenham), but the code is horrible). Better use a programming language (nearly any will do, even good old `basic` does this kind of thing quite smooth)

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult but i can send you a thread that shows how to do it, you can inspire yourself with this.

[**Thread**](http://www.instructables.com/id/Batch-game-movement-simple/step2/Code-2-Grid-confined-movement/)

But intereact with the map, like place block like Minecraft style, it's possible, but interact like a lever or something like that, i don't know if it's possible.